# Magura MT7 on Commencal Meta AM V4.2 Race

Tags: brakes

I would like to mount a set of Magura MT7 brakes on my Commencal Meta AM V4.2 (Race) with 200mm discs front and rear and a RockShox Lyrik Fork.

Which adaptors do I need?

Is there anything else to care about?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the answer from Commencal customer service :

MT7 with 200mm disc on the front without adapter
MT7 with 200mm disc on the back with +40mm PM/PM adapter. 180mm disc would not fit on the back because there is not enough space in the frame to place the caliber.

Comment: Great work - thank you for coming back with closure.   Do please click the "accept" button to the left of this answer, so that SE knows this is what worked for you.